# rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production gives error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, web-deployment, webdeploy

When I run the command: `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "93.188.167.2" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

So I guess my server is not listening on port 5432. So how do I solve this?

I know I have to edit some file so in addition to the instructions on how to actually edit the file (I guess it is the file named postgresql.conf?) please also tell me where I should find it.

My web application is on this directory at the server: /home/admin/www/webstudio

EDIT: I have already tried my best to follow the instructions given here: http://alexbachuk.com/launch-rails-4-application-with-passenger-and-nginx/

Comment: This question belongs to serverfault.com

Comment: These kind of questions are very often asked here, but okey, I'll try that Forum then.

Comment: check the port may be it is running on `5433` and host should be perfect for development eg: `localhost`